# Installing OpenSSL inside a docker image

Tags: c++, ubuntu, docker, openssl, dockerfile

I'm working with Docker and I have the following Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt update && apt install -y \
        bc \
        build-essential \
        cpio \
        dosfstools \
        g++-multilib \
        gdisk \
        git-core \
        libncurses5-dev \
        libncurses5-dev:i386 \
        python \
        squashfs-tools \
        sudo \
        unzip \
        wget \
        locales \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

WORKDIR "/sedutil"

CMD ["/sedutil/images/autobuild.sh","-h"]
```

I added to the list "libssl-dev" and "openssl" . Now I'm tryng to complie some c++ code inside the docker. It seems that the compiler does not find the openssl headers because it returns

```
fatal error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
#include <openssl/evp.h>
```

I think that adding "libssl-dev" is not enough. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Header `openssl/env.h` not exists in library. Maybe you think about `openssl/evp.h`

Comment: Sorry for my typing error. I edited my post: the error is with <openssl/evp.h>

Comment: The makefile that I used to compile the code, uses:

CC=x86_64-linux-gcc
CCC=x86_64-linux-g++
CXX=x86_64-linux-g++

If I change it in

CC=x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
CCC=x86_64-linux-gnu-g++
CXX=x86_64-linux-gnu-g++

It seems to compile but if I test the code, the result is that libraries are not linked in the correct way. Sorry for my stupid questions but I'm not confident with compilers.

Comment: Show me a your Makefile.

Comment: I solved. In practice, changing the compiler in my makefile is not the correct solution. I modified my code and now it works. Thank you